# Certain statements printing twice

Tags: c

In a hangman program I'm writing, words with two of the same letter, such as "eel" or "bee," upon the user entering "e" the first time and then trying to enter "e" for the second prompt, will display "You've already guessed this letter" twice. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(){

char w[13][3] = {
        { 'c', 'a', 't' }, //0
        { 'd', 'o', 'g' }, //1
        { 'r', 'a', 't' }, //2
        { 'e', 'e', 'l' }, //3
        { 'c', 'o', 'w' }, //4
        { 'o', 'w', 'l' }, //5
        { 'e', 'm', 'u' }, //6
        { 'b', 'a', 't' }, //7
        { 'e', 'l', 'k' }, //8
        { 'p', 'i', 'g' }, //9
        { 'b', 'e', 'e' }, //10
        { 'h', 'e', 'n' }, //11
        { 'f', 'o', 'x' }, //12
};

char u,
    newline,
    dis[16];

int random,
    guesses = 3,
    finish = 0;

_Bool successfulGuess = false;

srand(time(NULL));
random = rand() % 13;

    printf("Animal %d\n", random); //check random number
    printf("---------\n\n");
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    u = getchar();
    newline = getchar();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        if (w[random][i] == u){
            successfulGuess = true;
            dis[i] = u;
        }
        else {

            dis[i] = '_';
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        dis[j] = dis[j];

    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("%c", dis[i]);
    }

    if (successfulGuess == false){
        --guesses;
    }
    printf("\n\nGuesses left: %d", guesses);
    printf("\n\n");

while (guesses > 0){
    finish = 0;
    successfulGuess = false;
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    u = getchar();
    newline = getchar();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        if (u == dis[i]){
            successfulGuess = true;
            printf("\nYou already guessed this letter.\n");
            printf("\ninput = dis[i]\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
        }
        else if (w[random][i] == u){
            successfulGuess = true;
            dis[i] = u;
            printf("\ninput = array char\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
        }
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            printf("%c", dis[i]);
        }

        if (successfulGuess == false){
            guesses--;
            printf("\n\nbool statement\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
        }

        if (guesses == 0){
            printf("Sorry, you've run out of guesses.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (dis[i] != '_') {
                finish++;
            }
            if (finish == 3){
                printf("\n\nYou guessed the word!");
                guesses = 0;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why do you have  `for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){         dis[j] = dis[j];     }` in your program ?

Comment: What's the intended purpose of `for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ dis[j] = dis[j]; }` cycle?

Comment: Please read about the "Minimal" in ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Why do we need to see an array of all the "working" possibilities? If your random selection is working take it out and hardcode the problematic case. In short: don't post *"here's all my code, find my bug"*, rather *"I've whittled my code down to the most essential version of the program that demonstrates a problem"*.  That will focus your question, and you might find your own bug in the process...

Comment: +1 for posting a MCVE. (Well I guess it's not *minimal*, but it certainly is CVE)

Comment: @HostileFork, thanks for the tip. I should have done that. I'm just new here. :)

Comment: Why are you repeating the same code multiple times instead of enclosing it in a `do..while` loop or something like that?

Comment: @CoolGuy I put that there to permanently store the values into the array. I believe I did that before I took the first prompt out of a loop. Maybe I don't need it anymore. I'll look into it.

Comment: @CoolGuy, I couldn't get it to work in a single while loop. Maybe it will work if I initialize all of the array to '_' first.

Comment: My first thought when I looked at the code was the result array should be initialized to '___'.  My second thought is that there is no need to printf() a warning if the user selects the same char again.  After all, that is a valid thing to do for certain words (and therefore, allowable for any word.

Comment: @user3629249 It tells the user that they already entered the letter because it doesn't take a guess away but they need to know it's a waste of time. Why would they enter the same letter when they got all instances of that letter the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping i three times even if you have already shown the message. I think it should break ather the message:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    if (u == dis[i]){
        successfulGuess = true;
        printf("\nYou already guessed this letter.\n");
        printf("\ninput = dis[i]\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);

        /* BREAK HERE */
        break;
    }
```